# Make the screen Flash from Mac OS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I using different build scripts for package my apps. Some of them running a while and it would be great to have a visual notification the script is ready.

I already use the notifications center with an Apple Script but something it is not alarming enough. Is it possible to run and Applescript or a command line command to let the screen flashes. A plus would be to flash in different colors (green for OK and red for build failed).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a site where users get help with writing code when they hit a stumbling block and need help working through the problem. So it is expected that you show that you are working on code not looking for someone to write it for you. Please show us where you are stuck in your code and we will be more than happy to assist

Comment: @mcgrailm What is actually the difference between pasting wrong code or ask for an idea? I didn't ask someone to write it for my I just ask for a function name or other idea and in fact i made a lot of research and couldn't find a way.

Comment: The difference is that you show no signs of trying to solve your own problem in your post. You simply asked is it possible to ... and then you ask for a bonus item; Again showing no effort to figure it out. it just comes across like you were just asking for someone to do the work for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas...

**Easiest:**

Go to Terminal->Preferences->Advanced and change to `Visual Bell` then do

```
tput bel
```

**Coolest:**

Here is a little scipt I wrote to save the current Desktop background and then set it to green for 3 seconds and then reset it back to what it was. Of course, if you like it you can make it do red for fail pretty simply. All you need to do is save the red.jpg and free,jpg files below in the /Library/Desktop Pictures folders as red.jpg and green.jpg. Then save the script below as `notify` and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x notify
```

and run it with

```
./notify
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to save current wallpaper
saveWallpaper(){
osascript<<EOF
tell application "Finder"
    set theDesktopPic to desktop picture
    set theName to displayed name of theDesktopPic
    return theName
end tell
EOF
}

# Function to set the wallpaper
setWallpaper(){
echo $1
osascript<<EOF
set desktopImage to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/$1"
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell
EOF
}

# Start of actual script

# Save current wallpaper
saved=$(saveWallpaper)
echo Wallpaper is: $saved

# Set wallpaper to green for 3 seconds
setWallpaper "green.jpg"
sleep 3

# Restore wallpaper
setWallpaper "$saved"
```

**Using some sound:**

For success:

```
osascript -e 'beep 1'
```

For fail:

```
osascript -e 'beep 3'
```

Or how about:

```
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff -v 2
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
say finish
```

or

```
say there is a problem
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked! He is asking for a visual effect **not** an audio effect!

Comment: Yes your are right, why not to open a big "red image" file?

Answer (score 1):

This will flash the terminal screen:

```
tput flash
```

You can flash your other terminals like this:

```
tput flash >/dev/ttys002
```