# Draw red rectangle around entire screen on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to draw a red "border" around the entire screen somehow? I don't want to draw inside my application's window. And I want to be able to use other programs while this red border is shown.

I want to really signal to the user that the computer is in a special mode.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588065/make-the-screen-flash-from-mac-os-terminal/24589734#24589734

Answer (score 5):

Windows need not be opaque and can be set to ignore mouse events, using this it is quite easy to do what you wish. In outline:

a) Create a NSView subclass with a drawRect: method which draws a semi-transparent (< 1 alpha value) red border inside its frame.

b) Create an NSWindow subclass. Use NSBorderlessWindowMask as the style. Set backgroundColor to clearColor, opaque to NO, level to something that suits you - say NSScreenSaverWindowLevel, ignoreMouseEvents to YES, canHide to NO, etc. Set the window size/location to (one of your) screen(s). Set its contentView to your view from (a).

You now have a "window" which is a just a outlined semi-transparent red rectangle, create one and your screen is outlined as you wish.